# FilterExpression IN DynamoDb

Tags: php, json, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I have a PHP API querying DynamoDb. I am trying to filter the results by a list of strings

```
$eav = $marshaler->marshalJson($json);

$params = [
  'TableName' => $tableName,
  'IndexName' => 'tsType-tsTimeclockSortKey-index',
  'FilterExpression' => 'firstName IN :firstName',
  'KeyConditionExpression' => 'type = :type,
  'ExpressionAttributeValues' => $eav
];
```

I can filter based on one name, but I want to send a list of names and return all that match. If I send

```
{firstName: 'john'}
```

> **returns:** [firstName: 'John', lastName: 'doe']

All johns are returned. When I add another name, everything gets filtered out and the API returns an empty array

```
{firstName: 'john, sam'}
```

> **returns:** [ ]

What do I need to change in order to return all johns and/or Sams if they exist using the FilterExpression

Comment: Try enclosing the `:firstName` in parentheses: `firstName IN (:firstName)`, like [in the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html).